# Which characters in UTF8 can have upper/lower case pair?

Tags: utf-8

I know of a-z (A-Z), å (Å), ä (Ä), ö (Ö). But is there any official definition of which characters actually have a sibling in another case?

Answer (score 2):

This is language specific. But do check out [Case Mappings](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch05.pdf#G21180). This is part of the standard.

> **5.18 Case Mappings**
>
> Case is a normative property of characters in specific alphabets such as Latin, Greek, Cyrillic,
> Armenian, and archaic Georgian, whereby characters are considered to be variants of a
> single letter.

You may also want to check the [European Alphabetic Scripts](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch07.pdf) part for language specific information.

Comment: Thanks! When you think of it, of course it must be language specific. For it to be accepted answer, I'd need the case mappings for the different languages. (Maybe they are in the European Alphabetic Scripts? I didnt really understood if all the specifics were there, if that is so I was just ignorant and this shall be the accepted answer :))